# IF DEFINED for more than one variables?

Tags: scripting, batch-file

Currently I am doing this in my batch file and it works fine

`IF DEFINED var1 (do something) ELSE (do something else)`

Now I want to check more than one variables are defined or not with an `AND` operator between them. How can I achieve that?

for example something like

`IF DEFINED(var1) && DEFINED(var2) (do something) ELSE (do something else)`

**Update:**
I know I can do nesting but I am looking for a clean approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest your second if inside the (do something)

```
IF DEFINED var1 (**IF DEFINED var2 (do something) ELSE (do something else)**) ELSE (do something else)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to perform two IFs consequently, like you can see in [@Vinnyq12's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190531/if-defined-for-more-than-one-variables/6190592#6190592). The ELSE part can be related to only one IF, so you'll have to repeat it for each IF. If you wish to avoid repeating the same operation, you can do something like this:

```
IF DEFINED var1 IF DEFINED var2 GOTO iftrue
do something else
GOTO continue

:iftrue
do something
:continue
…
```